# usb-serial modem packet limit to 500 bytes

Tags: serial-port, usb, kernel, packet, modem

I am using sierra wireless modem MC8790V with TI's kernel 2.6.37, and noticed that ping from one unit to another is possible only if ping data length is limited to 479 (ping -w 479), any larger length fails. Not only that it fails, but later there is no more ping in the smaller length (until reseting the received unit). 
Is anyone jere familiar with this? Is it because packet length of bulk tansfer is limited to 512? maybe some bug in usb-serial driver or in my specific sierra wireless driver ?

Thank you for your time,

Ran

Answer (score 0):

It's the wireless modem.  There's no such limitation in standard "ping", in 802.11 or in Linux.  For example:

```
ping -s 2048 192.168.1.17
PING 192.168.1.17 (192.168.1.17) from 192.168.1.150 : 2048(2076) bytes of data.
2056 bytes from 192.168.1.17: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=1.323 msec
2056 bytes from 192.168.1.17: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.257 msec
```

Comment: The problem can also be in the driver (usb-serial or seirra modem driver). What did you mean when saying that it is the modem ?